# Headphone Daemon - for Linux?

Tags: linux, headphone-jack

Is there a headphone daemon for Linux like there is for maemo?  It is really convenient that whenever you unplug your headphones, the media player automatically stops playing.

Comment: It seems unlikely that would you describe would actually exist - largely because of the fact that the kernel probably wouldn't need to know itself. It'd be a major hack, so I'd be surprised if you find such a thing. Don't let it stop your trying, though.

Comment: Maybe a simple program that get list of devices from PulseAudio, and checks if a new device with type of headphone is connected, do the job. But how to getting list of PulseAudio devices (with their types) is the point.

Answer (score 1):

the hda driver, covers most of the new HD sound cards now has a way to detect plug changes. So if you did have a newer sound card, an input event happens when ever you change headphones. An input event could be mapped to a virtual keypress, such as mute. With that, just map the keypress to "MUTE" or one of the other multi-media keys.

Comment: Ok, I will have to read up on that.  Thanks for the info.